# How can I connect MySQL to Discord.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, discord.js

In this code, I tried to connect MySQL to Discord.js, but when I ran the command, I encountered such a result. How can I fix this or can I connect MySQL to Discord.js differently?

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("discord.js");
const mysql = require("mysql");
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "25m"
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if(err) throw err;
   
});
  
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("test")
    .setDescription("test"),
  
    async execute (client, interaction) {
        
        connection.query(`SELECT * FROM cypter WHERE id = '2'`,function(result) {
                interaction.reply({content: `Result:${result}`})
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am also using the mysql package. I am doing it this way:

```
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "25m"
    port: //Enter port,
});

var connection = pool.getConnection(function (err, con) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error DB connect: " + err);
        throw err;
    }
    else {
        connection = con;
        console.log("Connection established.");
    }

});
```

For my Queries I need to use ` to sourrund table and column names like (I removed the '' from the 2 because I thought it is a number if not you can use it again):

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM `cypter` WHERE `id` = '2';",function(result){
    interaction.reply({content: `Result:${result}`})
})
```

Comment: ı am getting this error "Result:Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column '2' in 'where clause'"

Comment: Then maybe try again with surrounding the 2 with '' otherwise I do not know which type your database uses for the column id

Comment: now ı am getting this "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"

Comment: Now you can do like (I am assuming id are unique):

let id = result[0].id
let ex = result[0].example
let ex2 = result[0}.example2